# Ability to read, insert, delete, update of Case under OEM Embedded Admin license

Tags: licenses, oem, platform-license

In [OEM User License Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm) is written following:

> OEM Embedded Admin—A contractually restricted Enterprise Edition
> Salesforce admin license that’s required on all initial orders. It’s
> used to configure and administer the OEM application. This license
> prohibits providing access to or use of any CRM functionality.
> **Prohibitions include**, but aren’t limited to, create, read, update, and
> delete (CRUD) on Leads, Opportunities, **Cases**, Solutions, Forecasts,
> and Campaigns.

If I understand correctly then user with **OEM Admin license** should NOT be able to create/read/update/delete Case. I ordered '*Force.com Platform Embedded Edition (Admin User) - OEM*' using Partner Order App. The Salesforce license has been assigned to my user. I logged in using user with OEM Admin user license and **I expected** that I will NOT be able to create Case, but I was able to create/update Case.

Please, can you explain me what I am missing, because I expected not be able to create Case?